# Is this a carpenter ant?

Tags: entomology, species-identification, ant

I stumbled upon a few hundred of these swarming around two different places in my living room today. They kind of look like a carpenter ant to me, but I'm not sure.

Also, I'd love to know how you identified the ant.

// EDIT, per a helpful suggestion, I'm in Los Angeles, CA, US. We just had rain come through within the last 4-5 days and it has since dried up.

[image: winged ant that is black in color]

Comment: Welcome to biology stack exchange. With insect identifcation it often helps to know a little about your geographic location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a carpenter ant...it's possibly a [Pavement Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavement_ant) (*Tetramorium
caespitum*) - only it's a male & hence winged....for identification...follow these [guidelines](http://www.wvu.edu/~exten/infores/pubs/pest/hpm3002.pdf)-

> Pavement ant workers are small, l/8-inch to 3/16-inch
>   long, and blackish brown with light-colored legs and two spines at the
>   end of the thorax. A distinguishing character, visible with a hand
>   lens or microscope, is the series of fine parallel groves on the head
>   and thorax

Comment: This is completely wrong. It cannot be a Tetramorium because there is no post-petiole between the thorax and the abdomen, and it is not a male but a queen as you can deduce by the absence of external reproductive organs at the end of the abdomen and by the fact the the head is fully developed with eyes relatively small compared to the head and mandibles entirely developed. The concave thorax indicates that this ant is from the genus Camponotus, also known as carpenter ants.

Answer (score 0):

Hymenoptera, Formicidae, Formicinae, Camponotus sp (queen). "Carpenter ant"

The unique segment between the thorax and the abdomen indicate this ant is in the subfamily Formicinae; the color pattern, the shiny cuticle and the concave thorax indicate this ant is from the genus Camponotus. It has wings so it is either a queen or a male, and you can exclude that this a male by the absence of external reproductive organs at the end of the abdomen and by the fact the the head is fully developed with eyes relatively small compared to the head and mandibles entirely developed.